# Graphs Dashboard doesn't work as Guide. (It outputs more complecated graphs actually.)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I was running the sample following the [Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/graphs), but the graph does not appear as in the Guide.(The first image is the sample and the second image is what was actually displayed.)
What could be the cause? (Do I have to tweak some settings or buttons to get it to follow the guide?)

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36VX9.png)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cA1TC.png)

Here is the code and version I ran for reference.

Code

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import datetime
import tensorboard
```

```py
# Define the model.
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy'])
```

```py
(train_images, train_labels), _ = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
train_images = train_images / 255.0
# Define the Keras TensorBoard callback.
logdir="logs/tb/fit/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir)

# Train the model.
model.fit(
    train_images,
    train_labels, 
    batch_size=64,
    epochs=5, 
    callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

Version

```py
print(tf.__version__)
2.5.3
print(tensorboard.__version__)
2.10.0
```

Best Regards.

Comment: I don't see any code that would show the graph - could you point out that section of the code?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
In this sample, the log_dir specified in callbacks is referenced and parsed from the TensorBoard process.
The graph is visualized on the UI provided by this process.

The TensorBoard startup command is as follows.

`/usr/local/bin/tensorboard --logsdir=<logs_dir> --bind_all`